# Sencha Touch SelectField Issue

Tags: javascript, css, ios, sencha-touch

I am creating a form with two cascading select fields in Sencha Touch 1.1.

[image]

After selecting a Make, the model list is filtered so that only the Models related to the Make get displayed.  After the first selection the list appears correctly.

[image]

If another Make is selected with more Models than the first selection, the data is correct but the layout is not.

[image]

How can I fix the layout of the list after the items are refreshed?

Comment: What version of Sencha-Touch are you using?

Comment: @ToddBFisher - I'm using v1.1.  I've updated the question.

Comment: You can set the height  and width of you select panel dynamically as follows    Ext.getCmp('yourSelectField').getListPanel().setHeight(150);             Ext.getCmp('yourSelectField').getListPanel().setWidth(70);

Comment: @heyjii I'll try that next week although I'd prefer to let it size dynamically.

Comment: @heyjii - setting the height and width does prevent the issue.  If it is still an issue on an actual device I'll work out some code that sets the height based on the number of items and the height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

What is your target device(s)? One thing I have noticed is that using Sencha-Touch in a desktop browser can have some display issues when compared to running it on an iPad simulator or device. Assuming Windows Safari is not your target browser I suggest testing it on your target device/simulator and see if it still happens.

Comment: My target device is an Apple iPad 2 and I don't currently have one to test on.  I'll be able to test it on the simulator - I'll see how that goes next week.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it on a simulator or device yet.